# how use MQTTAsync of paho mqtt c

Tags: mqtt

how use MQTTAsync of paho mqtt c, why all conn_opts set same as the example, and set the right url,  it can't connect to the mqtt broker? return errorcode 6

[image]

Comment: Please do NOT post images of code. They are hard to read, impossible to search for, and impossible for people with screen readers. Post as text and use the toolbar to format it properly

Comment: got it, thinks for remind

Answer (score 0):

Error code 6 says: "A NULL parameter has been supplied when this is invalid."
It indicates that a the option struct was not filled in properly.

Please post some more of your code *as text*. It's impossible to look at the image of the code that you posted!

Comment: already solved the problem! and got the usage of stack overflow, thinks who comments